# Why would we put a module inside a class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, namespaces

In Ruby, I see that it can be useful to put classes inside modules for the sake of namespacing. I also see that it's possible to put modules inside classes. But I don't see why you'd do that.

Modules are generally mixed into classes, right? So, *what would be the purpose of defining a module inside a class?*

Comment: Pattern is found in Lita ChatOps Handler class. https://github.com/litaio/lita/blob/master/lib/lita/handler/common.rb

Answer (score 61, accepted):

We could use it when writing ape-like code like this:

```
class DrugDealer
  module Drug
    def happy?; true; end
  end

  def approach(victim)
    victim.extend Drug
  end
end

o = Object.new
DrugDealer.new.approach(o)
o.happy? # => true
```

---

Another example that would be more practical in the real world is to have mixins that are only applied by subclasses.

This is useful when some *facets* of a thing apply to some subclasses and other facets apply to other subclasses, without there being enough order in the way these aspects apply to make way for a clear class hierarchy (tree). Think multiple inheritance! A simplified example:

```
class Person
  def handshake
    :sloppy
  end

  def mind_contents
    :spam
  end

  module Proper
    def handshake
      :firm
    end
  end

  module Clever
    def mind_contents
      :theories
    end
  end
end

class Professor < Person
  include Proper
  include Clever

  # ...
end
```

And so on. Kind of nice, when used sensibly. Even super calls and constructors (I didn't define any here though) flow through all the mixins and classes the way I want them to.

Answer (score 12):

I've since run into a use case in a large Rails app with complex namespacing. A simplified example:

```
# app/models/invoice/dependents/item.rb
class Invoice
  module Dependents
    class Item
      # Define invoice item
    end
  end
end
```

Here `Invoice` is a class of its own, but is also a good namespace for its dependent items. We can't say `module Invoice` because that constant is already defined as a class, but we can still use it as a namespace.

### Giant Caveat

If you use a class as a namespace, and you're using Rails, ensure you **do not accidentally declare that class elsewhere**. Autoloading will ruin your day. For instance:

```
# app/helpers/invoice/dependents/items_helper.rb
class Invoice       # This line will cause you grief
  module Dependents
    module ItemsHelper
      # view helper methods
    end
  end
end
```

The fact that `class Invoice` is stated in this file creates a load order dependency; if this file's `class Invoice` line is executed before your intended class definition, **your intended class definition may not work properly**. In this example, I can't declare that `Invoice` sublcasses `ActiveRecord::Base` if `Invoice` has already been declared with no parent class.

You **could** require your "true" class definition file at the top of another file, but at least in a Rails autoloading scenario, you'll have less wrangling to do if you do this instead:

```
# app/helpers/invoice/dependents/items_helper.rb
module Invoice:Dependents::ItemsHelper  
  # view helper methods
end
```

With this syntax, Rails will see the `Invoice` constant and use autoload to look it up, finding it in your model file and defining it the way you intended.

Comment: Good explanation of the caveat -- I just hit that too. But if you go with the suggested approach (`module Invoice::Dependents::ItemsHelper`), what if you want to reference other classes in the `Invoice::Dependents` scope? I'm finding I have to include the full class name (`Invoice::Dependents::OtherClass.method`), which is annoyingly verbose.

Comment: I believe this caveat was fixed with the introduction of the Zeitwerk autoloader. The classic autoloader's deprecation cycle will start with rails 6.1

Answer (score 7):

```
class Image
    module Colors
        Red = ...
        Blue = ...
    end
    include Colors
end

include Image::Colors

Image.new.set_pixel x, y, Red
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess it’s really just about using a class as a namespace, which is sometimes just more convenient that putting everything in a module. I’ve never seen that in practice, but it’s perfectly valid Ruby code either way.

The only real-life scenario I can think of is using EventMachine in a class:

```
class Api
  def initialize
    EM.start_server "0.0.0.0", 8080, Server
  end

  module Server
    def receive_data (data)
      # do stuff
    end
  end
end
```